# Using NPM Tor-Request for Javascript and using new IPs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently exploring javascript (node.js) to send requests to a server. I am attempting to use tor-request to randomize the IPs of the post requests I send but am having difficulty randomizing the IPs programmatically. According to [Tor-Request Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tor-request) I should be able to do this simply by using

`tr.newTorSession;`

but it doesn't actually randomize the IP again.

My current code is this

```
var tr = require('tor-request');

tr.request('https://api.ipify.org', function (err, res, body) {
  if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Your public (through Tor) IP is: " + body);
  }
})
tr.newTorSession;
tr.request('https://api.ipify.org', function (err, res, body) {
  if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Your public (through Tor) IP is: " + body);
  }
})
```

In my console I should be receiving two different IP addresses but instead I am receiving the same IP, why is this?

Comment: tr.newTorSession is incorrect, it should be tr.renewTorSession and there is a callback to the function as well...

`tr.renewTorSession((err, msg) => {
  if(err)
    return
  tr.request('https://api.ipify.org', (err, resp, ip) => {
    console.log('ip: ' + ip)
  })
})`